# ibm on demand new application + application group + folder definion

Tags: ondemand

At first I generated the field with 7 character, when I  got the below error,  I deleted; application, application group, and folder.Then I re-generated , application, folder and group with the field with 33 character.
I still have the below error while loading afp file to on-demand.
Any idea?
Error:
***Row 1:  The string "33333-5109741" has a length of 13 and the field has a maximum length of 7***

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all definitions, re-generated, appgroup, app and folder. Then with afp file I genereated index, resource and load the afp successfully.